# Meteor: How to find array of object with matched array of selector?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

Suppose I have array of string:

```
var lcArray = ["this", "is", "array", "of", "title"]
```

I need to find all object with lC field match with one of lcArray. I did this:

```
var qC = _.forEach(lcArray, function(lc) {
  MyCollection.find({lC:lc}, {
    fields: {lC:1, title:1, src:1, sC:1, _id:0},
    reactive: false,
    transform: null
  }).fetch();
});
console.log(qC);  // return ["this", "is", "array", "of", "title"]
```

I need this output:

```
[
    {
        lC: "array", title: "Array", src:"cat", sC:"cat"
    },
    {
        lC: "title", title: "Title", src:"bear", sC:"bear"
    }
]
```

How to find array of object with matched array of selector? thank You,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator in your query as it selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array:

```
var lcArray = ["this", "is", "array", "of", "title"];
var qC = MyCollection.find({"lC" : { "$in": lcArray } }, {
    fields: {lC:1, title:1, src:1, sC:1, _id:0},
    reactive: false,
    transform: null
}).fetch();

console.log(qC);
```

Comment: this is first time i use $in. learn a lot and it's work... thank You Sir,,,

Comment: @KarinaL No worries, glad you learned something new useful :)